# Why does IS_ERR_VALUE cast negative MAX_ERRNO to an unsigned long?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, error-code

In [include/linux/err.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/include/linux/err.h), there are the following defines:

```
#define MAX_ERRNO       4095

#define IS_ERR_VALUE(x) unlikely((x) >= (unsigned long)-MAX_ERRNO)
```

The idea is to check for a valid error number returned in the place of a pointer, but why does MAX_ERRNO has a unary `-` in front of it before being cast as unsigned? It seems like this would result in x being compared to the maximum long minus MAX_ERRNO instead of to 4095.

Comment: Because the pointers with addresses 0x0000 .. 0x0fff are valid (okay, first 16, IIRC, addresses are used to represent NULL PTR). But the upper space is dedicated for *invalid [never used] pointers*. NB: we are talking about virtual addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like an optimization to use only **one** comparison to check to see if `x` is between `-4095` and `-1`, aka a valid error code. For a `signed long` you'd need two comparisons:

`(x >= -4095 && x < 0)`

Casting -4095 to an `unsigned long` results in `0xff...ff001`, which only has 4094 integers above it before reaching `ULONG_MAX`. These values are also invalid pointer addresses at the end of the address space (hence why this range is used for error codes in functions that return void pointers).

Thus, the condition will return true if `x >= 0xff...ff001`, which is true for the signed range of `-4095` to `-1` (the valid error code range).